# How to repeat calculations but with different value

Tags: matlab

I'm a beginner working on a matlab project recently, in a part of my work,I have to do the calcultions for different values of k(as described in the code summary), the question is how can I do the calculations again with different k , without copy/pasting the code again ?

```
clc
clear
Tinf = 15;
h = 100;
Tb = 200;
k = 204;
L = 9e-2;
DL = L / 9;
D = 3e-2;
A = zeros(170,170);
C1 = -k * pi * (D/8) ^ 2 / DL;
C2 = -k * DL * pi / 4 * D / 8 / (D/4);
Cntr = 1 : 17 : 170;
Con = zeros(170,1);
%rest of the code which has variables of K
```

Comment: Functions. :-) use k as input to the function.

Comment: due to some limitations in the body,I can't use functions.

Comment: "_limitations in the body_" ??? ... please explicit the reason why you cannot use function, as it would be the most direct answer to your question. If you really cannot use function, please provide code with at least one repetition of the calculations, so people can see exactly what is duplicated and how to streamline it.

Comment: Also, reading your comment to one of the answer "_I have to deliver just one .m file_", you can make this `m` file a function, which allows to have as many internal (_sub_)functions inside the same `m` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the lines

```
clc
clear
```

and the line assigning to `k`. Then turn it into a function (called, e.g., `calculation`) file instead of a script file by adding the line

```
function result=calculation(k)
```

at the top. In your calculation leave the answer in the `result` variable and it will be returned from your function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short code for that, using anonymous functions:

```
% Parameters:
L = 9e-2;
DL = L / 9;
D = 3e-2;

% Functions:
C1 = @(k) -k * pi * (D/8) ^ 2 / DL;
C2 = @(k) -k * DL * pi / 4 * D / 8 / (D/4);

% Variable (assuming the calculation is on int from 1 to 100):
k = 1:100;

% Result:
y1 = C1(k)
y2 = C2(k)
```

`y1` is simply the result of function `C1(k)`, and the same for `y2`.
Hope that's clear enough ;)

Comment: I edited the question, you're right but the code isn't just c1 and c2,it continues to 160 lines,Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why you can't warp everything in a function like `function y = calc(k)` then drop the `k = 1:100` and at the end add somthing like `y = C1(k)+C2(k)`?

Comment: I have to deliver just one .m file, and there are so many k variables that i can't convert all of them to functions of k.

Comment: Even if the code is 1600 lines you can still use anonymous functions (because you cant use regular functions) to preform a repeatedly needed calculations. What do I miss?

Comment: You're so right,I just was searching for another way rather than converting all my C's to functions of k,I think there must be more efficient ways.

Comment: Another option is that your .m file will be a function, and then you can add [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) inside it, which might be slightly more efficient, and will give you all the functionality of a real (i.e. not [anonymous](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)) function.

Comment: I made contact with the relating professor , I can use another .m file as a function so problem is solved,I'm just so sorry to take your time.